# Deadlock in Ricart–Agrawala algorithm when logical timestamps are same

Tags: synchronization, mutex, clock, distributed-computing, mutual-exclusion

I am trying to implement Ricart–Agrawala algorithm for mutual exclusion on a distributed system. As per my understanding, it uses logical timestamp http://blog.8thlight.com/rylan-dirksen/2013/10/04/synchronization-in-a-distributed-system.html to order the events.

But assume that there are 10 nodes in the distributed system. Node-2 and Node-5 have their logical counter value equal to 3. Now if both of them try to send a request to each other to enter critical section, request message will be received with same logical time stamp value 3. Now Node-2 has its own request and request from Node-5 with same time stamp. This is same with Node-5 also.

In this case, Both Node-5 and Node-2 will never respond to each other as they are waiting for response from each other. So there is a deadlock. How this is avoided in the algorithm.

Please correct me if my understanding is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

In case of equal timestamps, the process with the lower ID wins. You may find more details on slides:

- 36 of [this lecture](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/courses/02222/Spring_2011/W9L2/Chapter_12a.pdf) by the Technical University of Denmark,
- 14 of [this lecture](http://tele.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/lehre/ws01/dsys/Lectures/Lecture12.pdf) by the University of Freiburg